# JSONPath, How to write (create) nested element (Java)

Tags: java, json, nested, jsonpath

I want to create a json file. I know json simple, but the JsonObject and JsonArray aren't fast enough for me. I want the same efficiency as yaml (for finding and writing values with path).

I want to write this example :

```
{
  "test": {
    "test1": 564,
    "test2": "der",
    "list": [
      "tes4",
      "test5"
    ]
  },
  "exList": [
    "tes4",
    "test5"
  ]
}
```

The **question** is how to write the json part with JsonPath ?

- DocumentContext#add doesn't seems to work
- DocumentContext#put needs strange args

[image: code sample, includes both add & put method calls]

With this sample code, I'm getting this error:

> `PathNotFoundException: Missing property in path $['test1']`

[image: main method and execution results]

(Sorry, I'm French.)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean strange arguments? You can do:

```
String path = "$"
String key = "newValue"
int value = 1

yourJson.put(path, key, value)
```

Comment: How can we add new element into nested element into Json using JsonPath?

like put("$.parent.child", key, value)